# How to set minimum value for a SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

I want to set a column minimum value

Column type is `int`

I want to set minimum value of 0

So if I update the column with -32 it should automatically set column value to 0

Comment: Not sure why the database should do this? Shouldn't you just do this  in the code?

Comment: i can do but it is easier if database is doing :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is to force the calling code to correct their data rather than magically alter it on insert. To do that, add a check constraint:

```
Alter Table MyTable
    Add Constraint CK_MyTable_Col Check ( MyCol >= 0 )
```

Comment: so it is not possible to make mssql do what i want ?

Comment: Technically, you could write a trigger that would hack the inserted values, but it would be much better for the calling code to be corrected so that it doesn't try to write a negative value into that column.

Comment: @PokemonCraft - Btw, if a value less than zero is invalid, you should still add the check constraint even if you fix the calling code. The reason is the account for some other system accidentally trying to insert a negative or someone changing your code at a later date and not accounting for this restriction.

Comment: @PokemonCraft - Whether the database data type can store the value isn't the issue. You want the check constraint to ensure that the type of data being stored is valid. Sure an int can store negative values (billions of them in fact) but in designing a database you want to ensure that the values for a given column are as correct as possible. Assume a nefarious developer will come along one day and try to stuff a negative value directly into your column bypassing your application.

Comment: thomas i am the only developer of my project :)

Comment: @PokemonCraft - You are the only developer *right now.*. What happen if you win the lottery tomorrow and sail off to the Tahiti? What happens if the scope of the project expands? It is best to develop with the mindset other developers will eventually use your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Check Contraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) ..